# Change encrypted password?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, passwords

Trying to make users available to change their password, but since the password is encrypted, users cant change it without entering the encrypted password first.

When users click "change password" they get sent to change.php which then returns them to profile.php?error=wrong_pw

Not used to hashing passwords since I've only done "simple" sites with php so far, without any security. Which is also why this is easily exploitable by hackers.

**Change.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

require 'dbc.php';
if (!isset($_POST['password']) || !isset($_POST['newpassword']) ||   !isset($_POST['renewpassword'])) {
header('Location: ../profile.php?error=wrong_info');
exit();
}

$user = $_SESSION['id'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
$renewpassword = $_POST['renewpassword'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$user' AND pwd='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

if($newpassword == $renewpassword){
if($newpassword != ""){
  $newsql = "UPDATE users SET pwd='$newpassword' WHERE id='$user'";
  $newresult = mysqli_query($conn, $newsql);
  header('Location: ../index.php');

}
else{
  header('Location: ../profile.php?error=empty');
  exit();
}

} 
else{
header('Location: ../profile.php?error=match');
exit();
}

} else{

header('Location: ../profile.php?error=wrong_pw');
}
```

**profile.php**

```
<?php require "inc/header.inc.php"; ?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['u'])){
$u = $_GET['u'];
}else{
$u = $_SESSION['id'];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$u'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

?>

<div class="container mt-3">
<table class="table">
<tr>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Username</th>
  <?php
    if ($u === $_SESSION['id']) {
      echo "<th>Password</th>";
    }
  ?>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $user['email']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $user['uid']; ?></td>
  <?php
    if ($u === $_SESSION['id']) {
      echo '<th><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#leModal">Change</a></th>';
    }
  ?>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
 <form action="change_theme.php" method="post">
 <center><button class="btn btn-primary themebutton" type="submit" value="Change theme" action="change_theme.php">Change theme</button></center>
 </form>
 <div class="modal fade" id="leModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Change Password</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="article_q" action="engine/change.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>">
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Current Password"><br><br>
      <input type="password" name="newpassword" placeholder="New Password"><br><br>
      <input type="password" name="renewpassword" placeholder="Re:Password"><br><br>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" value="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php require "inc/footer.inc.php"; ?>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question or problem?

Comment: Right; what isn't working the way you want it to? what results are you getting back or not? checking for errors at all? Your question is unclear (for me).

Comment: What you're asking for is unclear. It would be **beneficial for you** to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Please read through that and you'll see how Stack Overflow works, *"learning the ropes"* as it were. It will give you a good idea on how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help you have a better and positive experience here, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel you are missing the concept of encryption.

There should be no way to retrieve a string from a hash because it is a one way algorithm.

The process of reseting a password would be the following:

1. User is asked to type the old password and the new password.
2. User fills the data and Submits.
3. **The old password that the user entered is hashed with the same algorithm you used to hash the real old password from the database.**
4. You compare the hash between the real old password from the database and the ‘old’ password the user entered.
5. If they match, you update the registry where the old password was, and replace it with the new one hashed.

If you check it out, you will see it is logical. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To change/reset the password user must be logged in first then he can update his/her password providing current password. If user doesn't know his/her password then forgot password has to be done. By this way you can validate password is changed by authorized/valid person only.

However in your case you can change this query to update password without validation

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$user'";
```

It's better to validate user either by email/sms before updating password.